# Django webapplication Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime. in Heroku

Tags: django, python-2.7, heroku, tensorflow

I have try to deploy my AI application in Heroku with Tensorflow. Im getting error like  `Failed to load the native Tensor Flow runtime`.

[image: Error message from heroku while start the server.]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is **ImportError: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromString** as per the stack trace.

This happens when you have more than one versions of Python installed, You are probably running the compiled module with a different interpreter than the one you compiled the module with.

Python can be built with an internal Unicode representation of UCS2 or UCS4.

> Newly created Python applications on **Heroku** default uses the *Python*
>   *3.6.2* runtime.
>
> You can specify an arbitrary version of Python to be used to run your
>   application. read docs [python-runtimes heroku devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes)

Comment: It is more than that. It is not different Python versions, but usually caused by building a binary for a Python package against a Python 2.7 version which has a different Unicode character set width defined at installation time, than what the target Python 2.7 is using. You can see a discussion of the issue under section 'Unicode character sets' of http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/installing-custom-python-version-into.html

Comment: What is odd, is that since UCS4 is what is usually used for Linux, this suggests that the Python 2.7 installation being used was configured for UCS2. If Heroku is shipping UCS2 compiled Python, that goes against typical practice for Linux distros. Presuming that binary Linux wheels on PyPi would be all UCS4, that would cause lots of problems if they have.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton You can edit my answer and add these info. May be that will help.

Comment: I have tried above things , but no hope, still getting same error.